# How to pass data in array from one vc to another?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm in trouble with passing array data from one vc (which is table view controller, where I have news with come categories). I put these categories in array, then sort this array for unique elements, and this sorted array (which contains about 7 categories) I want to pass to another view controller.

**What I have:** I've created bar button item "Filter" and create an action for this button, called "filterButtonTapped". Inside action I've called method sorting array and called pushViewController

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

//this is sortedArray
var categories: [String]?

//this is sorting method 
func sortingArray() {
        var arrayOfAllCategories = [""]
        if let  rssItems = rssItems {
        for item in rssItems {
            //print(item.category)
            arrayOfAllCategories.append(item.category)

        }
        arrayOfAllCategories.remove(at: 0)
        categories = arrayOfAllCategories.unique
        }
    }

}

//this is IBAction 
 @IBAction func filterButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        sortingArray()
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FilterViewController") as! FilterViewController
        secondVC.arrayOfcategories = categories ?? [""]  
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
        print("filter button tapped")

    }
```

**The problem is** that 
 in the second view controller this array of categories is appearing (I print it and see the result), but cells apparently dont see this data, because this table view is empty after launching app and also nothing happens when I tap the button:

```
class FilterViewController: UITableViewController {

var arrayOfcategories: [String]? 

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        print(arrayOfcategories)  //this print prints array in the console 
    }

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return arrayOfcategories?.count ?? 0

    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryCell", for: indexPath) as! FilterCell
        let category = arrayOfcategories?[indexPath.row]

        cell.categoryLabel.text = category

        return cell    
    }



}
```

What am I doing wrong? How pass this array and use it to fill cells?

Comment: It sounds like you are passing the array correctly. It's far more likely you aren't setting the table view data source and delegate in your `viewDidLoad()` method. Scratch that, you are subclassing a `UITableViewController`, not a `UIViewController`, so this can't be the issue.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint within `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {` and ensure that it is being called?

Comment: Actually I've set a breakpoint and it isn't being called. All these tableViewDelegate methods aren't called

Comment: They may be misspelled? That's something that happens frequently, especially if you simply copy and paste code in.

Comment: I've wrote a mockArray like this ["1", "2", "3"] and put this in datasource methods, and this array is not displayed... :(

Comment: First, two things. One, instead of using `navigationController.pushViewController`, simply use MainViewController's `show` method. Two, you don't have to call `tableView.reloadData()` in `viewDidLoad` because UITableViewController automatically does that when the view loads (`super.viewDidLoad`).
Regarding your issue, can you please post the code of your FilterCell? And did you create the cell in your Storyboard. If not then you'll have to register it as mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Seems you're not registering your `UITableViewCell` here, add this line to `viewDidLoad` if you've created the cell programmatically (if you're using nib then register cell using nib parameter):

```
tableView.register(FilterCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell")
```

Add an observer for `arrayOfcategories` for when it sets to reload your data to the `UITableView` like this:

```
var arrayOfcategories: [String]? {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't help to solve the problem :( anyway thank you!

Comment: Could you debug this? Add a print inside the `didSet` that prints out `arrayOfcategories ` and tell me what you get. Since you're printing it in many other places too make sure you're getting the output from `didSet` print only.

Comment: I've remove all prints and called only one in didSet and  I've got filled array with actual data, something like that: Optional(["Medicine\n      ", "Sport\n      ", "People\n      ", "Economy\n      ", "World\n      ", "Hi-Tech\n      "])

Comment: Did you check my update? But missing the register should produce a crash. Could confirm if the cellForRow is getting called now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add these methods: Register Nib (*if you've created the cell programmatically*) and try to pass number of section 1:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(FilterCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        print(arrayOfcategories)  //this print prints array in the console 
    }

   override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}
```